# ExoPlayer2 - resizing video after playerView.setRotation(90)

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am testing ExoPlayer2 using the google exoplayer-codelab-00 app https://github.com/googlecodelabs/exoplayer-intro . The goal is streaming from an IP camera. I have to rotate the camera video stream  from landscape to portrait, shown on device in portrait mode.

I changed surface type to TextureView, in PlayerActivity.initializePlayer set playerView.setRotation(90). The video appears correctly rotated, but it is scaled at the initial size which would have been shown without the rotation, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMtgS.png).
I tried changing width and height in playerView.getLayoutParams() + playerView.setLayoutParams(), but the video is never shown higher. Change of RESIZE_MODE_FIT to RESIZE_MODE_FILL just expands the video to fit the new width, but the height is not changed, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abH4H.png).

Setting player.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT) makes no difference either.

IMO some layer of the view stack does not get rotated with the playerView.setRotation(90) and the unrotated dimensions somehow constrain the rotated video. I want the rotation fixed, it is called before setting media item. The device will always be positioned in portrait mode (fixed installation). Thanks a lot for any hints, I am completely new to Android.

Comment: Can you try this instead `exoPlayerView.getVideoSurfaceView().setRotation(90);`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it did not make any difference.

But setting the desired rotation in PlayerView.applyTextureViewRotation() rotated the video and set to fullscreen, while keeping the UI layer in portrait mode, as required. I have the whole ExoPlayer in sources, being built as a local module to my app, so modifying the source is trivial. I will have to learn how to change the videoSize.unappliedRotationDegrees param to avoid mods to the ExoPlayer code.